# How to calculate values from dynamic list

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I had a list of inputs that were dynamically created, who's ID was appended to each input's name, what would be the best way of getting the value of each line item and then calculating a line by line total, as well as a grand total?

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="CompetencyList[0].Score">
    <input type="text" name="SkillsList[0].Score">
    <input type="text" name="LineTotal">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="CompetencyList[1].Score">
    <input type="text" name="SkillsList[1].Score">
    <input type="text" name="LineTotal">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="CompetencyList[2].Score">
    <input type="text" name="SkillsList[2].Score">
    <input type="text" name="LineTotal">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    Grand Total: <input type="text" name="grandTotal"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself? If so, please post some code so we can help debug your issues.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Everything could be challenging for someone without experience but it would be a great opportunity for you to research a little... it's a quite simple problem to resolve

Comment: Your HTML doesn't match your question.  There is only one line there.

Comment: @RobertMcKee added the missing <tr>s & </tr>s

Comment: I have tried a few things, but don't have much experience with jquery. Stumbled over getting the values with the appended id in their name.

Comment: @TonyD There are many ways of doing it.  Adeneo has one such solution, which is to not find the id, but all the inputs inside a shared containing element (he used `td`, but you could also use `tr` if your values spanned multiple columns).  You could also use `.prev`/`.prevAll` to get preceding elements, and likely a large number of other options as well.

Comment: As a side note, why `LineTotal` and not `LineTotal[0]`, and you might consider having a singular item like `Scores[0].Competency`, `Scores[0].Skills`, `Scores[0].LineTotal`, which might fit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate each line

```
$('[name="LineTotal"]').val(function() {
    return $(this).closest('td').find('input').not(this).map(function() {
        return +this.value || 0;
    }).get().reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b });
});
```

once that's done, you'd calculate the total

```
$('[name="grandTotal"]').val(function() {
    return $('[name="LineTotal"]').map(function() {
        return +this.value;
    }).get().reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b });
});
```

```js
$('input').on('input', calculate);

function calculate() {
    $('[name="LineTotal"]').val(function() {
        return $(this).closest('td').find('input').not(this).map(function() {
            return +this.value || 0;
        }).get().reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b });
    });

    $('[name="grandTotal"]').val(function() {
        return $('[name="LineTotal"]').map(function() {
            return +this.value;
        }).get().reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b });
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="CompetencyList[0].Score">
            <input type="text" name="SkillsList[0].Score">
            <input type="text" name="LineTotal">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="CompetencyList[1].Score">
            <input type="text" name="SkillsList[1].Score">
            <input type="text" name="LineTotal">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="CompetencyList[2].Score">
            <input type="text" name="SkillsList[2].Score">
            <input type="text" name="LineTotal">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Grand Total:
            <input type="text" name="grandTotal" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: curious, if i wanted to multiply these values instead of adding a+b.. is there a special trick to that? a*b appears to return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your inputs dynamically, you can add to every input a class. Then you can use jQuery to get list of items that has this class. For example:

```
<input type="text" class="myInput" name="CompetencyList[0].Score">
<input type="text" class="myInput" name="SkillsList[0].Score">
<input type="text" class="myInput" name="LineTotal">
```

And in Javascript

```
var myImputs = $(".myInput");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JS fiddle to how I'd do it... https://jsfiddle.net/cz6sgbyc/1/

I have added classes of lineTotal, competencyScore, and skillsScore to the associated inputs, and an id of "grandTotal" to the grand total input.

Javascript:

```
function updateScores() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
  $('.lineTotal').each( function( index, input ) {
    var $parent = $(input).parent();
    var thisScore = parseFloat( $('.competencyScore',$parent).val() || 0 ) + parseFloat( $('.skillsScore',$parent).val() || 0 );
    grandTotal += thisScore;
    $(input).val( thisScore );
  });
  $('#grandTotal').val( grandTotal );
}

$(function() {
    $('input').change( updateScores );
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="competencyScore" name="CompetencyList[0].Score">
    <input type="text" class="skillsScore" name="SkillsList[0].Score">
    <input type="text" class="lineTotal" name="LineTotal">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="competencyScore" name="CompetencyList[1].Score">
    <input type="text" class="skillsScore" name="SkillsList[1].Score">
    <input type="text" class="lineTotal" name="LineTotal">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" class="competencyScore" name="CompetencyList[2].Score">
    <input type="text" class="skillsScore" name="SkillsList[2].Score">
    <input type="text" class="lineTotal" name="LineTotal">
</td>
<td>
    Grand Total: <input type="text" id="grandTotal" name="grandTotal"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```